# show audio player in colorbox using wordpress plugin shortcode

Tags: wordpress, colorbox

I'm using the mp3-jplayer plugin to play audio with playlist on my site. I want to show the player in popup, so I have installed the colorbox plugin and wrote a shortcode of the player inside the div that I'm calling to the colorbox function.

How can i show the audio player inside it or is there any other wordpress plugin that can be used?